# jQuerymobile button is only clickable/triggered once!

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hey!
I'm using jquerymobile Alpha 4.1 together with asp.net mvc3.

My situation:
I have two buttons in the footer with the url /booking/index/1 and /booking/index/-1.
They are used to step forward & backward (increasing / decreasing the date on serverside).

After clicking for example the next button, with url /booking/index/1, i step forward. Clicking it again does nothing, instead of stepping to the next date.

But now, if i click on the other button, with url /booking/index/-1, it steps back to the previouse day as expected. Although only once.

It loads the next day with "normal jqm ajax". I think it might be some history/"i am already on that page" problem?

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Related:

- [AJAX Request Help for next/previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278374/ajax-request-help-for-next-previous-page)
- [Multiple AJAX requests functions combined into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313809/multiple-ajax-requests-functions-combined-into-one)
- [JQM (jQueryMobile) Dynamically added elements not displaying correctly and CSS is not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249250/jqm-jquerymobile-dynamically-added-elements-not-displaying-correctly-and-css-is)

had the same issue